# nodeJS UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error

Tags: node.js, express, server

I'm just at a complete loss as to what is going on. This is my first attempt at a full stack mern app on my own and I just don't for the most part understand the code/explanations when I try to research the issue.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(morgan('dev'))


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/gundamstore' ,{ useNewUrlParser: true 
}, (err) => {
if (err) throw err
console.log('connected to the database')
})

// -------------------Don't forget to connect routes here-------------

app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log('this server is running on port 9000')
})
```

I was also getting body-parser is deprecated error but that went away when I put in the { useNewUrlParser: true } line. I've never gotten that error before and don't know why I got it to begin with.

If someone can please tell me what I'm doing to get this issue?

Comment: It's always best to use then() call for success and catch() call for failure while working with promises as mongoose.connect() returns a promise.

Comment: Since express >= 4.16.0 body-parser now a part of express, so you can just say `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: @AsafAviv Do I still need to have to the const bodyParser at the top?

Comment: No you don't, and you should delete it from your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(
  () => { /** ready to use. The `mongoose.connect()` promise resolves to undefined. */ },
  err => { /** handle initial connection error */ }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I didn't have mongoDB configured correctly. I needed to go into my system files and set up the PATH to the mongoDB bin directory. I still have a lot to learn about promises but I'm glad I got this figured out.